# Java interface static field lazy initialization

Tags: java, static, lazy-initialization

Given example

```
interface A {
    static int aInit() {
        System.out.println("Interface field");
        return 42;
    }
    int a = aInit();
}

class B implements A {
    static int bInit() {
        System.out.println("Class field");
        return 42;
    }
    static final int b = bInit();
}

A a = new B();
```

on both JDK8 and JDK10 prints just `"Class field"`. Direct access to `A.a` spawns its initialization and `"Interface field"` output.

This shows that **interface static field initialization is lazy**, which is not true for final static class field.

I can see [OpenJDK JEP draft](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8209964) about such laziness for classes, but is it a documented feature for interface? Or just a detail of JVM implementation?

Comment: No, it shows that using a class doesn't necessarily load its implemented interfaces, notably not when there is no need to.

Comment: It is a documented behavior. The interface `A` will not be initialized as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1. It is only initialized when either the field `a` or the method `aInit()` are called.

Comment: @manouti indeed, `T is a class and...` – not applied for interfaces, thanks! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: @AlexeyAdamovskiy Sure, just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a documented behavior. The interface `A` will not be initialized as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1. It is only initialized when either the field `a` or the method `aInit()` are called.